# Средства интеграции с другими языками

Tags: php

Какие в php есть средства интеграции с другими языками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретизируйте.

Если Вам надо две программы «подружить» — ну, откройте сокет/пайпу (или выделите общую память или любой другой метод IPC) и разговаривайте по известному протоколу (GPB, Thrift, MsgPack, JSON-RPC, BERT-RPC, … — нет им числа).

Если у Вас есть код на одном языке, и Вы хотите его использовать из PHP — конкретнее, о каком языке идет речь. Вообще, можно все, например, делается вокруг кода обертка для Zend API, подгружается через `dl()` и вызывается.

Ну или, как уже написали, `exec()`/`system()` — тоже вариант, для своих случаев. `popen()`, опять же, как частный случай общения через файловые дескрипторы (stdin/stdout/stderr, в данном случае). А то и вообще, запускаете программу через `exec()`, а она назад PHP по HTTP (на специальный адрес, куда принимаются запросы только от доверенной сети и/или с авторизацией) ответит.

Answer (score 0):

Есть функции `exec(), system()`. Посмотрите в этом направлении.